# Sort and create new columns by specific values using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to sort or group by dataframe by specific values from multiple columns with Pandas?

The dataframe that I am working with looks like below. I have 3 type columns with corresponding parameters `count` and `param`. For each type accordingly `count` and `param` column. I need to sort them based on type value, so the result would be new columns with its parameters for type = '1', type = '3', type = '3' and type = '6'.

[image]

The desired result looks like this:
[image]

What I tried is this, however, I  really not sure that this will do what I want, also with I would sort only type columns and not count and param as well:

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv(r'W:\...file.csv')

type_col = 1
new_column = 'group_1'

dataframe.loc[dataframe[type_1'] == type_col, group_1] = type_col
dataframe.loc[dataframe['type_2'] == type_col, group_1] = type_col
dataframe.loc[dataframe['type_3'] == type_col, group_1] = type_col
```

Here is the print output of dataframe.head(20):

```
print(dataframe.head(20).to_dict('list'))
{'type_1': [1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'count_1': [465, 254, 154, 16, 254, 261, 595, 119, 119, 751, 314, 68, 108, 118, 121, 58, 126, 87, 143, 43], 'param_1': [22, 21, 19, 21, 22, 21, 21, 20, 21, 21, 20, 17, 15, 24, 20, 23, 23, 21, 18, 18], 'type_2': [3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 1, 1, 4], 'count_2': [49, 15, 5, 16, 74, 3, 122, 38, 1, 63, 178, 67, 82, 3, 85, 27, 33, 74, 35, 35], 'param_2': [20, 19, 18, 21, 21, 17, 20, 20, 9, 23, 21, 14, 15, 17, 19, 23, 23, 21, 17, 19], 'type_3': [4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1], 'count_3': [3, 0, 0, 7, 39, 0, 8, 0, 0, 46, 4, 58, 44, 1, 18, 11, 31, 10, 20, 20], 'param_3': [18, 0, 0, 20, 21, 0, 17, 0, 0, 21, 18, 12, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 21, 17, 19]}
```

And the full dataframe:
print(dataframe)

```
    type_1  count_1  param_1  type_2  count_2  param_2  type_3  count_3  \
0        1      465       22       3       49       20       4        3   
1        1      254       21       3       15       19       0        0   
2        1      154       19       3        5       18       0        0   
3        3       16       21       1       16       21       4        7   
4        1      254       22       3       74       21       4       39   
5        1      261       21       3        3       17       0        0   
6        1      595       21       3      122       20       6        8   
7        1      119       20       3       38       20       0        0   
8        1      119       21       3        1        9       0        0   
9        1      751       21       3       63       23       4       46   
10       1      314       20       3      178       21       4        4   
11       4       68       17       1       67       14       3       58   
12       3      108       15       4       82       15       1       44   
13       3      118       24       6        3       17       1        1   
14       3      121       20       6       85       19       1       18   
15       3       58       23       4       27       23       6       11   
16       3      126       23       6       33       23       1       31   
17       3       87       21       1       74       21       4       10   
18       3      143       18       1       35       17       4       20   
19       3       43       18       4       35       19       1       20   
20       3      732       24       1      236       24       4       17   
21       3      175       16       1       37       16       0        0   
22       3      101       19       1       16       17       6        1   
23       3       45       19       1       24       18       4       15   
    param_3  
0        18  
1         0  
2         0  
3        20  
4        21  
5         0  
6        17  
7         0  
8         0  
9        21  
10       18  
11       12  
12       14  
13       17  
14       19  
15       21  
16       22  
17       21  
18       17  
19       19  
20       22  
21        0  
22        6  
23       20
```

Comment: can you do these for the original dataframe? #1 `df = pd.read_csv('path')`; #2 `print(df.head(20).to_dict('list'))` #3 copy the print output to the question. This is the better way to paste data here. do `pd.read_excel` instead of `pd.read_csv` if it is an excel.

Comment: Added print(df.head(20).to_dict('list')) to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape first, then create helper column `type1` used for groups by add to `MultiIndex` in [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), remove second level by [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last sorting by second level and flatten `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['type','count','param'],
                      i = 'index',
                      j='tmp', 
                      sep='_')
        .assign(type1 = lambda x: x['type'])
        .query("type != 0")
        .set_index('type1', append=True)
        .droplevel(1)
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
        )

df.columns = [f'group_{b}' if a == 'type' else f'g{b}_{a}' for a, b in df.columns]
```

---

```
print (df.head(10))
       group_1  g1_count  g1_param  group_3  g3_count  g3_param  group_4  \
index                                                                      
0          1.0     465.0      22.0      3.0      49.0      20.0      4.0   
1          1.0     254.0      21.0      3.0      15.0      19.0      NaN   
2          1.0     154.0      19.0      3.0       5.0      18.0      NaN   
3          1.0      16.0      21.0      3.0      16.0      21.0      4.0   
4          1.0     254.0      22.0      3.0      74.0      21.0      4.0   
5          1.0     261.0      21.0      3.0       3.0      17.0      NaN   
6          1.0     595.0      21.0      3.0     122.0      20.0      NaN   
7          1.0     119.0      20.0      3.0      38.0      20.0      NaN   
8          1.0     119.0      21.0      3.0       1.0       9.0      NaN   
9          1.0     751.0      21.0      3.0      63.0      23.0      4.0   

       g4_count  g4_param  group_6  g6_count  g6_param  
index                                                   
0           3.0      18.0      NaN       NaN       NaN  
1           NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  
2           NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  
3           7.0      20.0      NaN       NaN       NaN  
4          39.0      21.0      NaN       NaN       NaN  
5           NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  
6           NaN       NaN      6.0       8.0      17.0  
7           NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  
8           NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  
9          46.0      21.0      NaN       NaN       NaN
```

EDIT:

```
d = {'type_1': [3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'count_1': [465, 254, 154, 16, 254, 261, 595, 119, 119, 751, 314, 68, 108, 118, 121, 58, 126, 87, 143, 43], 'param_1': [22, 21, 19, 21, 22, 21, 21, 20, 21, 21, 20, 17, 15, 24, 20, 23, 23, 21, 18, 18], 'type_2': [3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 1, 1, 4], 'count_2': [49, 15, 5, 16, 74, 3, 122, 38, 1, 63, 178, 67, 82, 3, 85, 27, 33, 74, 35, 35], 'param_2': [20, 19, 18, 21, 21, 17, 20, 20, 9, 23, 21, 14, 15, 17, 19, 23, 23, 21, 17, 19], 'type_3': [4, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 6, 0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1], 'count_3': [3, 0, 0, 7, 39, 0, 8, 0, 0, 46, 4, 58, 44, 1, 18, 11, 31, 10, 20, 20], 'param_3': [18, 0, 0, 20, 21, 0, 17, 0, 0, 21, 18, 12, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 21, 17, 19]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), 
                      stubnames=['type','count','param'],
                      i = 'index',
                      j='tmp', 
                      sep='_')
        .assign(type1 = lambda x: x['type'])
        .set_index('type1', append=True)
        .droplevel(1)
        .reset_index())

df = df[df.duplicated(['index','type'], keep=False)]
print (df)
    index  type1  type  count  param
0       0      3     3    465     22
20      0      3     3     49     20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great on the example dataframe, but as I use the other, similar data I got ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Will try to figure out what's wrong. The error shows at .unstack()) line.

Comment: @g12345kk - Problem is in some row id duplicates value in `type` columns.

Comment: Is there a possible way how to detect the problematic rows?

Comment: @g12345kk - answer was edited.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked! And I noticed that duplicated values are zeros in type columns. Can I somehow define that 0 should not be consider, but they are not removed either?

Comment: @g12345kk - solution was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71044890/revisions).